# How to send mail in HTML format in Rails 2.3.11?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mime-types, actionmailer

I've only found solutions that work in Rails 3, so far.  How can I force emails sent with ActionMailer to be formatted as HTML, rather than plaintext?

**/app/models/franklin.rb (the mailer)**

```
class Franklin < ActionMailer::Base
  def activation(user)
    recipients      user.email
    from            "activation@rit.oncampusapp.net"
    content_type    = "text/html"
    subject         "OnCampus @ RIT Registration"
    body            :user => user
  end
end
```

**/app/views/franklin/activation.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  </head>
  <body>

Hi <%= @user.full_name %>,

This is your activation email for OnCampus @ RIT.  All you have to do is click the link below, and you'll be able to log in.

<%= link_to "Activate My Account!", "http://rit.oncampusapp.net/admin/activate?key=#{@user.activation_key}"%>

We hope to see you soon! :D

-- The OnCampus Team

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting in the activation action **content_type "text/html"** instead of  **content_type    = "text/html"**

Comment: I'm fairly new at Rails, so I'm not quite sure what you mean.  Could you please elaborate?

Comment: In the question your posted **content_type = "text/html"** is this a typo??

Answer (score 2):

Just paste this in your notifier/mailer model method - this will solve your problem

```
content_type  "text/html"
```